# Divide work among processes or threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am interning for a company this summer, and I got passed down this program which is a total piece. It does very computationally intensive operations throughout most of its duration. It takes about 5 minutes to complete a run on a small job, and the guy I work with said that the larger jobs have taken up to 4 days to run. My job is to find a way to make it go faster. My idea was that I could split the input in half and pass the halves to two new threads or processes, I was wondering if I could get some feedback on how effective that might be and whether threads or processes are the way to go.

Any inputs would be welcomed. 
Hunter

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a thread and a process? Introducing parallelization does not automagically make things take less time. There are classic, simple examples when it actually makes the computations slower. Are the computations [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel)? Has the code been profiled and optimized at all yet? Why not try that first?

Comment: The code was written by someone no longer at the company, so I have been working through it myself, no one seems able to tell me what some of the functions do. And the documentation is really poor. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way when optimising code, always, is to Profile it to find out where the Logjam's are IMO.

Sometimes you can find non obvious huge speed increases with little effort.

[Eqatec](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/), and [SlimTune](http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/) are two free C# profilers which may be worth trying out.

(Of course the other comments about which parallelization architecture to use are spot on - it's just I prefer analysis first....

Answer (score 3):

I'd take a strong look at [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) that was introduced in .net4 :) [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) might be especially useful for easy speedups.

Genereally speaking, splitting into diffrent processes(exefiles) is inadvicable for perfomance since starting processes is expensive. It does have other merits such as isolation(if part of a program crashes) though, but i dont think they are applicable for your problem.

Comment: Considering he says that it takes days sometimes, starting up a process isn't exactly going to be that expensive in this case (compared to what he's dealing with now).

Comment: true, but it all depends on the granularity of the paralellism he can get.. for a single machine data paralellism is probably the way to go, then when scaling to multiple machines, you'd use process paralellism of course (in addition to inprocess paralellism)

Answer (score 2):

If the jobs are splittable, then going multithreaded/multiprocessed will bring better speed. That is assuming, of course, that the computer they run on actually has multiple cores/cpus.

Threads or processes doesn't really matter regarding speed (if the threads don't share data). The only reason to use processes that I know of is when a job is likely to crash an entire process, which is not likely in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Use threads if theres lots of memory sharing in your code but if you think you'd like to scale the program to run across multiple computers (when required cores > 16) then develop it using processes with a client/server model.

Comment: +1, if the work is large enough to be split over multple machines process paralellisation is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) -- this sounds like a prime candidate problem for using it.

As for the threads vs processes dilemma: threads are fine unless there is a specific reason to use processes (e.g. if you were using buggy code that you couldn't fix, and you did not want a bad crash in that code to bring down your whole process).

Answer (score 1):

Well if the problem has a parallel solution then this is the right way to (ideally) significantly (but not always) increase performance.

However, you don't control making additional processes except for running an app that launches multiple mini apps ... which is not going to help you with this problem.

You are going to need to utilize multiple threads. There is a pretty cool library added to .NET for parallel programming you should take a look at. I believe its namespace is `System.Threading.Tasks` or `System.Threading` with the Parallel class.

Edit: I would definitely suggest though, that you think about whether or not a linear solution may fit better. Sometimes parallel solutions would taken even longer. It all depends on the problem in question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to communicate/pass data, go with threads (and if you can go .Net 4, use the Task Parallel Library as others have suggested).  If you don't need to pass info that much, I suggest processes (scales a bit better on multiple cores, you get the ability to do multiple computers in a client/server setup [server passes info to clients and gets a response, but other than that not much info passing], etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would invest my effort into profiling the application first. You can gain a much better awareness of where the problem spots are before attempting a fix. You can parallelize this problem all day long, but it will only give you a linear improvement in speed (assuming that it can be parallelized at all). But, if you can figure out how to transform the solution into something that only takes `O(n)` operations instead of `O(n^2)`, for example, then you have hit the jackpot. I guess what I am saying is that you should not necessarily focus on parallelization.

You might find spots that are looping through collections to find specific items. Instead you can transform these loops into hash table lookups. You might find spots that do frequent sorting. Instead you could convert those frequent sorting operations into a single binary search tree (`SortedDictionary`) which maintains a sorted collection efficiently through the many add/remove operations. And maybe you will find spots that repeatedly make the same calculations. You can cache the results of already made calculations and look them up later if necessary.